# Select model according to brand drop down

Tags: javascript, html

i have  two drop down boxes
 the first drop down contain the mobile brands 
and other contains the mobile models
i want  them to work like when in first drop down a brand is selected 
the second drop down will show models of that particular brand i want to do it with javascript
the drop down values are static values
how i can do that?

```
<select name="brand">
<option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
<option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
</select>

<select name="model">
<option value="Galaxy">Galaxy</option>
<option value="N8">N8</option>
</select>
```

The Drop down will be like the above ones

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax record on the first celect box change and fill it in the second select box. Jquery ajax will function  will send data to a function which will fetch data from database .

Comment: am not getting data from database

Comment: well got my answer here
http://www.tamilcodes.com/document.aspx?content=Tutorials&id=36